# Multiple areas of dynamic content in a page

Tags: pages, page-template, content

I am new in Wordpress and what I really can't find how to do is the following:
I have a new Page created from the CMS. This pages have different modules with text. Take for example this template http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/40000.html

There are three modules in the row with an icon, a heading and text. And below other four. How is possible so user be able to edit from wordpress each one of these modules separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you gave has a listing of three pages and four posts (which are dated). The same can be achieved by one of the following:

1. two different [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types), one per block, e. g. `post_type='products'` and `post_type='projects'`;
2. children of two another pages, e. g. children of "Products" in one block and children of "Projects" in another;
3. pages grouped by some [custom field(s)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields);
4. pages sharing two [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), one for each block.

And may be some other methods.

It's depends on what site structure you'll have and what type of navigation and some other things you prefer (manual or auto).

Comment: The problem here is that it's not flexible enough for arbitrary pages

Answer (score 3):

Use the spots plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/spots/

You can use it as a widget, a shortcode, or place 'template spots' in your theme that you can assign.

You could also use custom fields in metaboxes to add edit boxes for each field

edit:

You could always have a custom post type for each type of block, and a custom taxonomy, and display all posts in a certain term, e.g. for Page A you could have a 'page A top thirds' term and display posts in that